# Refrence Photo not showing in perspective view ( checked in the panel)

Tags: 3d-view

Im trying to match up my refrence photos from the perspective mode but as soon as I move the view it disapears, I did check the box as shown in the photo but still same is happening. 
thanks in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Isn't it because of your clipping range? It looks like the Y axis is disappearing rather soon. Just go to the *Sidebar > View > Clip start/End* and adjust the values.

Comment: Thank you that worked :)